# Start Shortcut (.ink) as administrator in Win8.1: Folder name contains symbol (& or =) error

Tags: batch-file, administrator, ampersand

The folder name of my folder contains the ampersand symbol "&", and in that folder i have at batchfile, batchfile.bat.

Lets say the path is:

```
C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\1 & 2\batchfile.bat
```

When creating af shortcut to run that batchfile, when not run as administrator, it works. But as soon as i run the shortcut as administrator, it will not open batchfile.bat and gives the error:

```
'C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\1' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Is there a way to bypass the ampersand (&), and run the program as administrator, whithout changing the name of the folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapt the *target* field of the shortcut from

```
"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\1 & 2\batchfile.bat"
```

to (here `/K` switch for debugging purposes, the `cmd`  window should stay open)

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /K call "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\1 & 2\batchfile.bat"
```

and finally to

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C call "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\1 & 2\batchfile.bat"
```

Tested with simplified path `"D:\bat\1 & 2\batchfile.bat"` as follows:

[image: adapted shortcut]

The script is as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
@SETLOCAL enableextensions
set "xx=%~f0"
echo stackoverflow 28077086 %xx:&=^&%
@ENDLOCAL
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\1 & 2\batchfile.bat"
```

That is "quoting the string" should cure thr problem.